# python 2.5 win32 build of pyopencv?

Tags: python, windows, binary, opencv

Does anybody have a link to, or has built themselves, a win32 build of [`pyopencv`](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/downloads/list) for Python 2.5?

I spent one or two entire days looking for it or trying to compile it to no avail. I deferred the task to later - and that later is now.

If anybody is willing to perform this task, I'll award them 500 bounty. Until then I'll pick up where I left off and just ask specific questions.

Comment: Looks like a fun one! It *should* be possible to compile with Visual Studio Express (or MinGW) installed, but the dependencies on NumPy and Boost.Python also need to be built (or have headers available) first...